# 'Rcpp_precious_remove' when trying to run regression

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to run a multilevel regression model when I get this error message in R

```
Error in initializePtr() : 
function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

This has only started happening today, before when I ran regression models this did not happen. I have tried reinstalling r but the error still persists. I am working with a large dataset of 300000 observations and 80 variables.

Comment: If you just stick the error string _into the search bar here at StackOverflow_ you thirtyfive hits.  In short, it's a 'frequently asked question' and a duplicate, and those tend to get closed.  Just upgrade the Rcpp package to be as current as the package you want to use, and which had been built against a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a version of [this issue](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/641), namely that there is a mismatch in the stack of binary packages (`Rcpp` > `RcppEigen` > `lme4`) so that

> the current situation means that lme4 fails unexpectedly for those installing it from CRAN as a binary and who expect the R package dependency system to ensure any dependencies are on the appropriate minimum versions.

Can you see whether

```r
install.packages("Rcpp", type = "source")
install.packages("RcppEigen", type = "source")
install.packages("lme4", type = "source")
```

resolves the problem?  This would depend on having development tools (compilers etc.) installed.

If @DirkEddelbuettel's comment above is correct, then you would only need `install.packages("Rcpp")` and not any of the rest of the machinery above.